# Why are all my Ubuntu based systems unable to connect reliably to internet or network all of a sudden, but my Windows systems can?

Tags: networking, 18.04, mate

I have 5 machines based on Ubuntu bionic. They are all desktops, 2 are connected by Ethernet and 3 are WiFi. All these devices are dropping connection to network, can't update in terminal or GUI, cant ping others, samba file server list unreachable, and internet drops seemingly at random.

The Ubuntu Machine I'm mostly concerned with is my main workstation running Ubuntu MATE 18.04.3, the others are running LinuxMint Tara. The network information in gui shows they are connected while this problem persists. I never get a network disconnect notification on panel.

What happens is this; as I'm browsing with any browser it may take long to load when I click a link or open a new tab, or when I open a browser window. This is usually followed by the browser displays a generic 'can't reach server page', but sometimes it just hanging and loads forever. Sometimes it can be fixed with disable then enable networking through MATE panel, or apt update. Sometimes apt update cant reach PPAs, and only can reach main repos for download. Sometimes apt update gets stuck at initial connection and hangs forever.

When this happens I also can't ping any machines on the network. If I reboot the problem is usually fixed for a few minutes but not all the time. It seems to fix itself if I use the network icon in notification area of panel to 'disable networking' then 'enable' it. The thing is that the issue returns whenever it wants. At random it will work again and I'll be able to update, ping other computers or browse online, but it will break inevitably.

My android devices do the same thing, the network shows as being connected, but browsers and apps do not work correctly. Because this is the case I thought my router was going out but my 2 dual boot Windows 7 are able to browse, download, stream and do anything with no problems. They cannot see the samba servers I had working just a few days ago. Windows is not having this issue at all so the router must not be the problem. It has got to be Ubuntu doing something I'm probably too much a Linux noob to understand.
On these dual boot machines, or any for that matter, cannot connect to samba servers. I get an error dialogue that states "Failure to retrieve share list from server".

I have been keeping all these machines updated and don't really do a risky things online. Well I guess I might because I do play this cracked version of Aliens Vs Predator 2 in wine and I'm sure its a very hacker populated game. The other day I played with a dude who claimed to be a network security specialist. I told them I was trans and got bullied for like an hour by another guy he was talking to.

I really need help. I noticed my router settings had a lot of devices in the list so I reset it to factory settings (probably because I've reinstalled OSes so much) and reconfigured everything to clean it up so to speak. I've reset the router many times and done power off, leaving unplugged for a minute or 2, and re powering device. The problem still persists only in my Ubuntu based systems. My main workstation is my biggest concern and it seems to be the worst of them all.

Can someone please help me out, and where should I start?
I do notice that on my main workstation I have 4 different IPv6 addresses, is that normal?

Thank you for your help because I haven't really had any major problems like this with Linux before. Everything has always just worked besides things that were easy to work around but this is beyond my understanding of a lot of things and the internet is necessary for me. I'm literally in tears because I'm trying to find a job and going through lot of personal problems and I need the internet to get through all of this.

The dual boot computers are my kids gaming computers and I guess I'll be using one of those for now because; 1) I don't want to install windows on my machine 2) I would feel like such a failure if I did. 3) My CPU doesn't even support Windows 7, its Kabylake gen and I don't have Windows 10, nor the money to pay for it.

**Why would this happen to every Linux computer at the same time? I have 5 of them and they all have this issue which just popped up.** 3 are new parts except the 2 that kids use to dual boot with Windows. Maybe it is the router and Windows is just handling whatever errors better than Linux can

Thank you very much for reading all of this. Here are some commands that I used to get some useful info for anyone who has the skills to evaluate what's happening.

```
ifconfig -a
enp0s31f6: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
inet 192.168.1.80 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 192.168.1.255
inet6 2600:1700:8be0:1950::3f8 prefixlen 128 scopeid 0x0
inet6 2600:1700:8be0:1950:2c61:904c:48ca:d3aa prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x0
inet6 2600:1700:8be0:1950:61f4:9b39:159:fda7 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x0
inet6 fe80::5ebd:1dda:5cd0:f5c5 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x20
ether 30:9c:23:9c:a0:88 txqueuelen 1000 (Ethernet)
RX packets 46729 bytes 41560601 (41.5 MB)
RX errors 0 dropped 2185 overruns 0 frame 0
TX packets 27998 bytes 6195132 (6.1 MB)
TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0
device interrupt 16 memory 0xdf200000-df220000
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING> mtu 65536
inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 255.0.0.0
inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 scopeid 0x10
loop txqueuelen 1000 (Local Loopback)
RX packets 1115 bytes 116212 (116.2 KB)
RX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 frame 0
TX packets 1115 bytes 116212 (116.2 KB)
TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0
```

```
lspci:
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 06)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 06)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH Thermal Subsystem
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH CSME HECI #1
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH SATA controller [AHCI mode]
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f0)
00:1c.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #7 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH LPC Controller (B250)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation 200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family Power Management Controller
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH HD Audio
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation 200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family SMBus Controller
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107 [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GP107GL High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
02:00.0 USB controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. Device 2142
03:00.0 PCI bridge: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1083/1085 PCIe to PCI Bridge (rev 03)
```

```
sudo lshw -C network
*-network
description: Ethernet interface
product: Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 1f.6
bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
logical name: enp0s31f6
version: 00
serial: 30:9c:23:9c:a0:88
size: 1Gbit/s
capacity: 1Gbit/s
width: 32 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k duplex=full firmware=0.8-4 ip=192.168.1.80 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
resources: irq:126 memory:df200000-df21ffff
```

```
ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s31f6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 30:9c:23:9c:a0:88 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.1.80/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp0s31f6
valid_lft 83376sec preferred_lft 83376sec
inet6 2600:1700:8be0:1950::3f8/128 scope global dynamic noprefixroute
valid_lft 2588975sec preferred_lft 601775sec
inet6 2600:1700:8be0:1950:61f4:9b39:159:fda7/64 scope global temporary dynamic
valid_lft 3434sec preferred_lft 3434sec
inet6 2600:1700:8be0:1950:2c61:904c:48ca:d3aa/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute
valid_lft 3434sec preferred_lft 3434sec
inet6 fe80::5ebd:1dda:5cd0:f5c5/64 scope link noprefixroute
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

```
ethtool -g enp0s31f6
Ring parameters for enp0s31f6:
Pre-set maximums:
RX: 4096
RX Mini: 0
RX Jumbo: 0
TX: 4096
Current hardware settings:
RX: 256
RX Mini: 0
RX Jumbo: 0
TX: 256
```

```
ethtool -k enp0s31f6
rx-checksumming: on
tx-checksumming: on
tx-checksum-ipv4: off [fixed]
tx-checksum-ip-generic: on
tx-checksum-ipv6: off [fixed]
tx-checksum-fcoe-crc: off [fixed]
tx-checksum-sctp: off [fixed]
scatter-gather: on
tx-scatter-gather: on
tx-scatter-gather-fraglist: off [fixed]
tcp-segmentation-offload: on
tx-tcp-segmentation: on
tx-tcp-ecn-segmentation: off [fixed]
tx-tcp-mangleid-segmentation: off
tx-tcp6-segmentation: on
udp-fragmentation-offload: off
generic-segmentation-offload: on
generic-receive-offload: on
large-receive-offload: off [fixed]
rx-vlan-offload: on
tx-vlan-offload: on
ntuple-filters: off [fixed]
receive-hashing: on
highdma: on [fixed]
rx-vlan-filter: off [fixed]
vlan-challenged: off [fixed]
tx-lockless: off [fixed]
netns-local: off [fixed]
tx-gso-robust: off [fixed]
tx-fcoe-segmentation: off [fixed]
tx-gre-segmentation: off [fixed]
tx-gre-csum-segmentation: off [fixed]
tx-ipxip4-segmentation: off [fixed]
tx-ipxip6-segmentation: off [fixed]
tx-udp_tnl-segmentation: off [fixed]
tx-udp_tnl-csum-segmentation: off [fixed]
tx-gso-partial: off [fixed]
tx-sctp-segmentation: off [fixed]
tx-esp-segmentation: off [fixed]
tx-udp-segmentation: off [fixed]
fcoe-mtu: off [fixed]
tx-nocache-copy: off
loopback: off [fixed]
rx-fcs: off
rx-all: off
tx-vlan-stag-hw-insert: off [fixed]
rx-vlan-stag-hw-parse: off [fixed]
rx-vlan-stag-filter: off [fixed]
l2-fwd-offload: off [fixed]
hw-tc-offload: off [fixed]
esp-hw-offload: off [fixed]
esp-tx-csum-hw-offload: off [fixed]
rx-udp_tunnel-port-offload: off [fixed]
tls-hw-tx-offload: off [fixed]
tls-hw-rx-offload: off [fixed]
rx-gro-hw: off [fixed]
tls-hw-record: off [fixed]
```

Sorry this was so long. If you help me I will love you forever. OK, since I love everyone in the world already I guess I already love you for reading this but still, thanks for even getting down to this line.

Comment: Seems like if non-Ubuntu systems (Mint, Android) have this problem, then yo have conclusively demonstrated that it's NOT an Ubuntu issue. Were this kind of issue happening on my network, I'd continue to sniff around the router as a primary suspect - cheap household routers drop connections when their device table gets filled up, and it's possible that WIN and Linux machines are simply connecting at different times or have different DNS or timeout settings. If this happened to your Android phone regularly on other networks, then I'd start looking at a Linux problem.

Comment: Do you use ipv6 outside of your local network? If not, you may want to try either setting ipv6 to link local only in your network manager settings or try disabling ipv6 completely if it is not in use. Another thing you may want to try setting a static IP for your local IP address on your machine in your network manager settings and also set the static IP for your Ubuntu machine in your router settings. Sometimes Ubuntu will have problems when the wifi frequencies are crowded by pesky neighbors but this shouldn't be an issue on a wired network. Also, you can try using a different DNS server.

Comment: However, if the Ubuntu machine is connected by wifi, you should run `sudo iwconfig $(iwconfig | grep wlp | awk '{print $1}') power off` to disable power management. Sometimes power management will time out and the connection will drop but it will still show as connected on your machine and so you will have to refresh the connection but I have only seen this happen with wifi.

Comment: You can run `iwconfig` to see if "Power Management" is on or off if you are using wifi.

Comment: **VOTERS PLEASE NOTE**: User has `Ubuntu MATE 18.04.3`. While there are other non-Ubuntu machines,  there is one Ubuntu flavor and that makes the question on-topic.

Answer (score 3):

I am officially a paranoid person who overthinks everything. Sorry I never replied here. I solved it.

Router was the issue. I got the router replaced and have had smooth sailing. New IPs and all my Ethernet machines are set as staticIP now. Thanks for the help though.